# Android service not holding for long

Tags: android

Created a script that is able to capture both outgoing and incoming SMS through registered service, this service works for about an hour and then the capturing stops, though Android showing the process and service running in the backgroud, but the actual expected capturing stops until I visit the app manually and it all resumes again for a short period. Here is the code I've put on App `pause/iddle`:

```
protected void onPause() {
    if(!TrackerService.isRunning){

        serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TrackerService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);

        mServiceReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(TrackerService.mAction);
        registerReceiver(mServiceReceiver, intentFilter);


     }

    super.onPause();
}
```

I already have the service registered in the manifest. Here is the complete manifest details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sentsms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sentsms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name=".TrackerService">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter> 
         </service>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are registering your receiver in the code, I suppose its getting unregister after the app is killed by android. I would suggest to register your receiver in manifest rather.
Hopes this solves your problem.

Comment: I already have the service registered in the manifest. Check the complete manifest details in my edit above.

Comment: Im talking about the broadcast receiver in this case.You can use them for listening to events in case of receiving sms or sending sms. You need to add the receiver in manifest.

Comment: Thanks, but all the examples am seeing of using broadcast receiver all seem to be for incoming SMS, none has been provided for outgoing SMS. I need to track both.

Comment: Hi, you can try this : http://www.mattquiros.com/blog/2012/10/11/how-to-track-or-monitor-outgoing-sms-or-text-messages-in-android/

Comment: Example provided on that page throws errors all over and the author does not reply to the so many pleas from people who have attempted to use it.

Comment: Tried adding an alarm that starts the service after every few seconds but that still doesn't solve it.

Comment: Hi,please try this..
http://vmtuong.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/android-content-observer-for-call-and-sms-logger/

Answer (score 0):

I guess sometime, system kill the service and then restart it, but because of Service's default  flag is START_STICKY, so the restarted Service will receive **empty** Intent

Service flag

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

Comment: @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Log.i("Status","Service Start");
        isRunning = true;

        // ContentResolver para obtener los SMS salientes
        contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, new mObserver(new Handler()));

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

Comment: That didn't solve either. The service works for a short period and then stops, though Android keeps on showing the the service is active.